# copying Notes/Comments from one sObject to another

Tags: apex, trigger, notes

I am trying to use the below code in my trigger to copy the Notes from my custom object to a newly created record on the *Demand* object:

```
List<Note> insertingNotes = new List<Note>();
List<Note> lstNotes = [SELECT Id, Title, ParentId, LastModifiedDate, createdbyid, body FROM Note where ParentId =:rq.Id];

for (Note eachNote : lstNotes){

    Note newDemandNote= new Note();
    newDemandNote.Body = eachNote.Body;                            

    newDemandNote.Id = eachNote.Id;
    newDemandNote.createdBy = string.valueOf(eachNote.CreatedById);
    newDemandNote.LastModifiedDate = eachNote.LastModifiedDate;           
    newDemandNote.ParentId = newD.Id;

    insertingNotes.add(eachNote);                            
    }

if (insertingNotes.size() >0){
    insert insertingNotes;
    }
```

But I am getting a compile error **Illegal assignment from String to User** on the line

```
newDemandNote.createdBy = string.valueOf(eachNote.CreatedById);
```

I also tried:

```
newDemandNote.createdBy = eachNote.OwnerId;
```

but no luck!

so what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newDemandNote.createdBy = string.valueOf(eachNote.CreatedById);
```

change to

```
newDemandNote.createdById = eachNote.CreatedById;
```

I believe we can't assign `createdById` field. **This field is not writtable.**

You may need to give user to set audit fields permission in user's profile.

**I suggest just remove all audit fields lines ..** rest code look good to me

Answer (score 1):

The correct API Name is `CreatedById`:

```
newDemandNote.CreatedById = eachNote.CreatedById;
```

Please note that this field is typically not writeable.