# trigger BeforeUpdate failed when inserting attachments into new record on Demand object

Tags: apex, trigger, attachment, notes

as a follow up [to my earlier question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110671/copying-notes-comments-from-one-sobject-to-another) I am now getting BeforeUpdate trigger errors when trying to insert attachments as it says the *ParentId* field is not writable.

so here below is the code that is supposed to copy all the attachments for the record from my custom object to the new record on the *demand* object in the **BeforeUpdate** event that fires when the record is updated:

```
// copy attachments:
List<Attachment> insertingAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
List<Attachment> lstAttachments = [SELECT Id, Body, Name, LastModifiedDate, contentType, OwnerId from Attachment where ParentId =:rq.Id];

for (Attachment att : lstAttachments){
    Attachment  newattch = new Attachment();  
    newattch = att.clone(false);
    newattch.body = att.body; // required field
    newattch.name = att.name;// required field  
    newattch.OwnerId=att.OwnerId;                           
    newattch.parentId = newD.Id;
    insertingAttachments.add(newattch);                           
    }

if (insertingAttachments.size() > 0){
    insert   insertingAttachments;         
    }

// copy Notes:
List<Note> insertingNotes = new List<Note>();
List<Note> lstNotes = [SELECT Id, Title, ParentId, LastModifiedDate, createdbyid, body FROM Note where ParentId =:rq.Id];

for (Note eachNote : lstNotes){

    Note newDemandNote= new Note();
    newDemandNote.Body = eachNote.Body;                            
    newDemandNote.Title=eachNote.Title;    
    newDemandNote.Id = eachNote.Id;
    //newDemandNote.createdBy = string.valueOf(eachNote.CreatedById);
    //newDemandNote.createdBy = eachNote.OwnerId;
    newDemandNote.ParentId = newD.Id;

    insertingNotes.add(eachNote);                            
    }

if (insertingNotes.size() >0){
    insert insertingNotes;
    }
```

the error I am getting is:

> Apex trigger System_Change_Request_Events caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: System_Change_Request_Events: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, attachment_before_insert: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.attachment_before_insert: line 39, column 1: []: Trigger.System_Change_Request_Events: line 310, column 1

**UPDATE - here is the trigger code for isUpdate:**

```
if (Trigger.IsUpdate && trigger.isbefore)
{
system.debug('(Trigger.IsUpdate && trigger.isbefore) BLOCK');
for (Request_for_System_Change__c rq : Trigger.new) {

system.debug('"for (Request_for_System_Change__c rq : Trigger.new) {" BLOCK');               

// Access the "old" record by its ID in Trigger.oldMap
Request_for_System_Change__c oldrecord = Trigger.oldMap.get(rq.Id);

system.debug('step 4 Record Type=' + oldrecord.RecordType.Name);

system.debug('in trigger get LineManagerName');
string lineManagerName = [SELECT Name from User where Id =: rq.Manager__c].Name;
system.debug('in trigger Line Manager name for Demand: ' + lineManagerName);           

if (rq.RecordTypeId == systemChangeRecordType)
    {           
if (rq.Status__c != OldRecord.Status__c && rq.Status__c == 'Convert to Demand') // && rq.RecordTypeId == systemChangeRecordType )
                {

rq.Skip_Validation__c=true;
system.debug('trigger CONVERT TO DEMAND step 2a SYSTEM CHANGE REQUEST - Approved and create demand for '+ systemChangeRecordType);

apm2__Demand__c newD = new apm2__Demand__c();
//+ oldrecord.RecordType.Name + '
newD.Demand_request_date__c = rq.Date__c;
newD.Project_Department__c = 'Systems';
newD.Demand_Title__c = rq.Request_Title__c;
newD.apm2__Criticality__c = rq.Request_Priority__c;
newD.Demand_Requested_by__c = lineManagerName;
newD.Prioritisation_points__c = rq.Benefits_Reasons__c;
newD.Demand_request_date__c = system.today();
newD.apm2__Business_Driver__c = rq.Benefits_Reasons__c;
newD.Demand_Status__c = 'New';
newD.Originating_Request__c=rq.Id;
                    newD.Assigned_Resource__c=rq.Assigned_resource_for_demand__c;
    newD.apm2__Demand_Type__c = 'Enhancement Request';

    // rq.Description_of_change_requested__c.length()>=149 ? rq.Description_of_change_requested__c.substring(0,150) :rq.Description_of_change_requested__c    
    string sDesc;
    integer iLen = rq.Description_of_change_requested__c.length();    

    if (iLen>=149){
      sDesc= rq.Description_of_change_requested__c.substring(0,150);
        }else     {sDesc= rq.Description_of_change_requested__c;}

    newD.apm2__Description__c = ' Systems Change Request  (' + oldrecord.Name + ') \r\n' + sDesc +' ... (see Request for full description)' ;
    newD.Extended_Description__c = 
    rq.Description_of_change_requested__c + ' \r\nExpected outputs:\r\n ' + rq.Expected_outputs__c
         + ' \r\nLegal / Regulatory / Compliance impact:\r\n ' + rq.Legal_Regulatory_Compliance_impact__c    ;
    newD.Additional_Information__c = rq.Anticipated_benefits_reason_for_change__c + ' \r\n' + rq.Additional_information_comments__c;
    newD.Department_Requested_by__c = rq.Department_Name_String__c;
                newD.Systems_Affected__c=rq.Systems_Affected__c;

    insert newD;
    rq.Demand__c = newD.Id;
    rq.Demand_Name__c=[select name, id from apm2__Demand__c where Id=:newD.Id].Name; //newD.Name;

    system.debug('New demand ID: ' + newD.Name);
    rq.Status__c='Converted';       

    system.debug('Status: ' + rq.Status__c);
    system.debug('Demand: ' + rq.Demand__c);

    // now lock the record to prevent tampering...                                          // Lock the request
    // Lock the request
    // Approval.LockResult lock(Id recordId) 
    // System.ApprovalProcess Approval=new System.ApprovalProcess();    
    // Approval.lock(rq.Id);
    // Approval.LockResult =  Approval.lock(rq.Id); 

    // Lock the request
    //Approval.lock(rq.Id);

    // copy Notes:

    List<Note> insertingNotes = new List<Note>();
    List<Note> lstNotes = [SELECT Id, Title, ParentId, LastModifiedDate, createdbyid, body FROM Note where ParentId =:rq.Id];

    for (Note eachNote : lstNotes){

        Note newDemandNote= new Note();
        newDemandNote.Body = eachNote.Body;                            
        newDemandNote.Title=eachNote.Title;    
        newDemandNote.Id = eachNote.Id;
        //newDemandNote.createdBy = string.valueOf(eachNote.CreatedById);
        //newDemandNote.createdBy = eachNote.OwnerId;
        newDemandNote.ParentId = newD.Id;

        insertingNotes.add(eachNote);                            
        }

        if (insertingNotes.size() >0){
            insert insertingNotes;
            }                                            

        // copy attachments:
        List<Attachment> insertingAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
        List<Attachment> lstAttachments = [SELECT Id, Body, Name, LastModifiedDate, contentType, OwnerId from Attachment where ParentId =:rq.Id];

        for (Attachment att : lstAttachments){
            Attachment  newattch = new Attachment();  
            newattch = att.clone(false);
            newattch.body = att.body; // required field
            newattch.name = att.name;// required field  
            newattch.OwnerId=att.OwnerId;                           
            newattch.parentId = newD.Id;
            insertingAttachments.add(newattch);                           
            }

            if (insertingAttachments.size() > 0){
                insert   insertingAttachments;         
                }
```

to clarify, line 310 is `insert   insertingAttachments;`

**UPDATE: here is the trigger attachment_before_insert on Attachment:**

```
trigger attachment_before_insert on Attachment (before insert) {

if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert)
{
    PPTriggerUtils triggerUtils = new PPTriggerUtils();

    triggerUtils.handleAttachmentBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
}

/*//Build list of Ids to be excluded from file check 
set<string> ExcludedIds = new set<string>();

//Project Object
for(apm2__Project__c p:[select Id, Name from apm2__Project__c]){
    ExcludedIds.add(p.Id);
}

//Project Task Object
for(apm2__Project_Task__c pt:[select Id, Name from apm2__Project_Task__c]){
    ExcludedIds.add(pt.Id);     
}

//Demand Object
for(apm2__Demand__c d:[select id, Name from apm2__Demand__c]){
    ExcludedIds.add(d.Id);          
}

//Change Control Object
for(Change_Control__c cc:[select id, Name from Change_Control__c]){
    ExcludedIds.add(cc.Id);         
}*/

for(Attachment a:trigger.new){

    //Set check attachment to true
    boolean CheckFileType = true;

    Id ids = a.ParentId;
    Schema.SObjectType ObjectName = ids.getSObjectType();

    if( string.valueOf(ObjectName) != 'Case'    && 
        string.valueOf(ObjectName) != 'Credit_Case__c' &&
        string.valueOf(ObjectName) != 'Loan_Application__c')CheckFileType = false;

    //Is user the API user?
    if( Userinfo.getUserName().contains('apiuser@bankofcyprus.co.uk') ||
        Userinfo.getUserName().contains('buser@bankofcyprus.co.uk')
        )CheckFileType = false;

    //If Checkfiletype equal true then check attachment contentType and then name. 
    if(CheckFileType == true){

        if(string.valueOf(ObjectName) == 'Case' || string.valueOf(ObjectName) == 'Credit_Case__c'){
            //Checks if a file is a ZIP file
            if(a.ContentType == 'application/x-zip-compressed'){
                a.adderror('ZIP files cannot be uploaded into Salesforce');
            }

            //Checks if a file is a HTML file
            if(a.ContentType == 'text/html'){
                a.adderror('HTM/HTML files cannot be uploaded into Salesforce');
            }


            //If you cannot check by contentType
            if(a.Name.contains('.')){
                list<string> sWrd = a.Name.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase();
                integer i = sWrd.size()-1;

                if(i>=0){
                    string ext = sWrd[i];

                    //Check if file is Rich Text Format
                    if(ext.toLowerCase() == 'rtf')a.adderror('RTF files cannot be uploaded into Salesforce');

                    //Check if file is Csv Format
                    if(ext.toLowerCase() == 'csv')a.adderror('CSV files cannot be uploaded into Salesforce');

                    //Check if file is Csv Format
                    if(ext.toLowerCase() == 'msg')a.adderror('MSG files cannot be uploaded into Salesforce');

                    //Check if file is Csv Format
                    if(ext.toLowerCase() == 'zip')a.adderror('ZIP files cannot be uploaded into Salesforce');

                }
            }
        }
        else if(string.valueOf(ObjectName) == 'Loan_Application__c'){
            //Checks if a file is not a pdf file

            integer endP = a.Name.length();
            integer staP = endP - 4;

            if(a.name.substring(staP,endP).touppercase() != '.PDF'){            
                a.adderror('Only PDF documents can be uploaded');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and line **39** is `Schema.SObjectType ObjectName = ids.getSObjectType();`

so it doesn't like the idea of an insert into the attachments table referencing a newly inserted record in the Demand object during a Before_Update...

so what am I missing here, surely I can copy the notes and attachments?

Comment: I believe it will be difficult to check this because I cannot find the line numbers 39 and 310. Can you highlight the lines in which you are getting the error.

Comment: I think the error was on `insert insertingNotes;`

Comment: Line 39 is in a separate trigger: `attachment_before_insert` - that is where I would look first - when you clone these attachments, you'll fire the before insert trigger on the clones

Comment: Checking `!myList.isEmpty()` before `DML` is unnecessary, but here it does tell us the list isn't `null`, or you would get your `NullPointerException` there. Error is definitely in the other trigger.

Comment: You need to post the entire code from both triggers involved.

Comment: `newDemandNote.Id = eachNote.Id;` and then inserting notes. It will give you error.

Comment: And are you sure ` insert    insert   insertingAttachments; ; ` this line is causing error. Because if  `insertingAttachments ` is null then before this line `if (insertingAttachments.size() > 0)` will give error.

Comment: @OurManInBananas As mentioned by crop1645, if you want a proper answer, you need to include the trigger "attachment_before_insert" in your question-- this trigger code is perfectly fine. In fact, I've done code like this before.

Comment: @sfdcfox: I have added the code for both triggers...

Comment: @DavinCasey: I have added the code for **both triggers**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now you can not transfer attachment from one object to another by just updating ParentId.

You will have to create/clone new attachment assign the clone to new parent and delete original copy.

```
List<Attachment> attachmentsToInsert = new List<Attachment>();

List<Attachment> attachmentsToDelete = new List<Attachment>();

Attachment tempAtt;


for(Attachment attachment: [
        SELECT SystemModstamp, ParentId, OwnerId, Name, 
            LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, IsPrivate, IsDeleted, 
            Id, Description, CreatedDate, CreatedById, 
            ContentType, BodyLength, Body 
        FROM Attachment 
        WHERE parentId=:'parentid']) {

    tempAtt=attachment.clone(false,false);
    tempAtt.parentId = quoteSelWrap1.quot.Id;

    attachmentstoInsert.add(tempAtt);
    attachmentsToDelete.add(attachment);

}

insert attachmentsToInsert;
delete attachmentsToDelete;
```

**EDIT 1**

After looking at Adrian Larson comment I realized that there is no issue in original code posted in question.

I tested it with some hard coded values and its just run fine on my dev org.

```
List<Attachment> insertingAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
List<Attachment> lstAttachments = [SELECT Id, Body, Name, LastModifiedDate, contentType, OwnerId from Attachment where ParentId ='5009000000SbT0s'];

for (Attachment att : lstAttachments){
    Attachment  newattch = new Attachment();  
    newattch = att.clone(false);
    newattch.body = att.body; // required field
    newattch.name = att.name;// required field  
    newattch.OwnerId=att.OwnerId;                           
    newattch.parentId = '5009000001D6dxd';
    insertingAttachments.add(newattch);                           
    }

if (insertingAttachments.size() > 0){
    insert   insertingAttachments;         
    }
```

So this issue is at due to error at line # 39 in attachment_before_insert trigger.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. OP *is* inserting new records.

Comment: Yes, you were correct, the issue was caused by the lines `Id ids = a.ParentId;` and `Schema.SObjectType ObjectName = ids.getSObjectType();` - as I had mistakenly commented the line `newattch.ParentId = newD.Id;` no *ParentId* was passed, throwing the **System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object** ! A similar error was on the *Notes* table,  the error was in the line  `insertingNotes.add(eachNote); ` instead of the correct `insertingNotes.add(demandNote);`

Answer (score 3):

This error indicates that you are trying to get the `sObjectType` of your `ParentId` when it is `null`. In other words, the new records you are cloning have a `ParentId` of `null`. Not sure where you are getting your `newD` record from, but if you're cloning it somewhere, it's possible you can resolve this issue simply by cloning with `preserveId=true`. For example:

```
system.assertEquals(null, someD.clone(/*preserveId*/ false), 'Blank Id');
system.assertNotEquals(null, someD.clone(/*perserveId*/ true), 'Populated Id');
```

If the Id is blank because you have not yet inserted `newD`, then you must insert the records first, before adding attachments to them.

In the long run, if you can redesign the `Attachment` trigger, you probably should. I find it pretty frustrating to have field requiredness enforced by faulty triggers with a `NullPointerException`. If you move the inner block of your `for` loop into another method, then you can immediately `return` if the `ParentId` is null. Otherwise, work a guard clause in there using the `continue` statement.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, yes, the ParentId was noty being passed for the attachment table, and in the Notes part, I had a bug in my insert notes code...

Comment: I just wish I could successfully lock the record now, but that's another question, and another headache! :)

Comment: @OurManInBananas Are you getting our answers confused?

Comment: yes, probably :), thanks for your answer, I will pass this advice on about that Attachment trigger

Comment: @OurManInBananas Yeah it just seems like you're giving someone else all the credit. :P

Comment: sorry but I awarded the bounty just before your answer showed up...in fact the part of his answer that really helped me was `So this issue is at due to error at line # 39 in attachment_before_insert trigger` which woke me up to the fact that I was not passing the ParentId of the new record in the *Attachments* table...also, he showed an example of code successfully inserting a record in that table. I am sorry if it looked like I had used your answer and given the credit elsewhere

Comment: @OurManInBananas That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. :)